# ASP.NET Membership: CSS being blocked by Deny users, page doesn't render correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a page that functions correctly but when i issue a deny user for the whole site it redirects me to the logon page which seems to work BUT the css is not working. Hence there is no styling..

Can anyone help? My web.config is like so

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

This logon page uses a site.master has the following style sheet but fails to style the document when the  above is included

```
 <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To confirm i i remove the  part above in web.config then it works hence the css is included and beng styled

I thought it might be something to do with the css being denied .. so i included the following but it makes no difference. I know the site.master is being rendered in the logon page because i see the headers etc..

```
 <location path="~/Content">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

I have also used firebug in firefox to view the css, if the authorization tags are included in web.config then it states there is no CSS. If i remove the tags then i can see the css and the page is rendered correctly.

I must be missing something. Any help really appreciated

thanks in advance

EDIT

Fiddler states that the site.css is moved??

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Location: /InmoCasaWebClient/Account /LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fInmoCasaWebClient%2fContent%2fSite.css
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2010 17:19:12 GMT
Content-Length: 201

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
```

### Object moved to [here](/InmoCasaWebClient/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fInmoCasaWebClient%2fContent%2fSite.css).

Comment: THanks everyone, this has been some really great advice.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the tilda (~) in your location's path attribute. If you look at the fiddler result, its a callback request for your css. so the unauthenticated request for the page is in turn making unauthenticated requests for resources (the css).

I generally try to place a styles directory at the root of the application, and then use a helper tool like [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) or my own helper methods to translate and avoid having to figure out the `../../` directory crawling.

Comment: Thanks ! that was it .. i remove the tilda and the / .. and all is well....  But a helper tool or t4mvc wouldn't help in the web.config though??  But i love the idea for t4mvc.. i will look at implementing in my code for using strongly typed views etc...

Comment: ermm one thing .. do you know if its possible to say that ALL directories under "CONTENT" should be allow users=*  or do i need to add a location for each sub directory in the web.config?

Comment: @mark, no, the helper tool would be for the master page files and any markup that would need a reference to a directory (images, css, scripts, etc). My experience with subdirectories has been to set it in the web.config or to place an additional web.config in the subdirectory with the authorization node defined with the rules I want. So I am not sure if it cascades down as I have always explicitly set it.

Answer (score 8):

Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see exactly what is happening to that resource? May shed light on the mystery. It should 403 if it is unauthorized. May be 404ing? If it's not in a virtual directory you could just write:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(directory traversing is flimsy)

**Update - now more info**

Nice fiddler use ;) Anyway, since it is 302ing (temporarily redirecting) your css files to require validation too the problem is your forms authentication.

You are probably running into the [runAllManagedModuleForAllRequest="true" problem](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html). Read that post for info.

**Or** set the all access to the Content folder to allow access. You're almost there but it would need to be:

```
<location path="Content">             
   <system.web>             
     <authorization>             
       <allow users="*" />             
     </authorization>             
   </system.web>             
 </location>
```

Comment: I am getitng object moved, i have updated my question with the fiddler stuff.... So i think what is happening is its requesting the site.css but its being redirected to the logon page as well for the site.css .. but i have entered the location info ... a little confused

Comment: glad that helped. I've updated my answer with the fix (fingers crossed)

Comment: Upvoted for pointing me in the direction of your "Run all managed modules" post, I was having the same problem and this was the culprit

Answer (score 5):

i had a similar problem. if it helps, i added permission (IUSR or depending on your OS) to the root web directory, it worked.

Comment: +1 this fixed it for me.  I'd added the AppPool user (`IIS AppPool\MyAppPoolUser`) but had forgotten about `IUSR`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The 302 is from the login framework redirecting you to login when requesting the CSS.

The trick here is your MVC app should not be configuring the security via web.config but rather you should be using the [Authorize] attributes on your controllers which will not interfere with your CSS.

Comment: Hi Wyatt, thanks! This a great tip thankyou... but considering that my app requires you to authenticate before having access to "ANY" page (only login) i think the web.config is a better approach...???  Otherwise i would have to inser the authorize attribute on every single method in every single controller...  Maybe i am not seeing the full picture?

Comment: I think if my app was basically open apart from certain pages then this would be a great idea, hence i could force someone to login if they wanted to use a specific page /controller function.. otherwise just let them through...  I hope i am on the right lines here??

Comment: Well, your app is open for certain pages -- such as login. Easy trick is to extend all secured controller from a base class. Also note that [Authorize] can cover entire controllers as well, no need to cover every method.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, avoid hardcoded paths to resources like JS or CSS files in your ASP.NET MVC views. Using /Content/Site.css does no better than ../../..

Use Url.Content helper:

```
<%=Url.Content("~/public/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply allow app to access your css file :

```
<location path="Style.css">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
```