# How is asp.net Authorization Rule preventing CSS to be applied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authorization

I am preventing anonymous access to my web application using `<deny users="?"/>`. Since I want login page to be accessible to anonymous user I used the following rule

```
 <location path="Login.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Since this rule prevented the css to be applied to the login page I used additional rule

```
<location path="Style.css">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

That fixed it and now css is applied to the login page. But before applying the above additional rule I checked the source of page in browser and found that there existed an entry for `<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and clicking the link, the browser did take me to my css file and displayed all the styles. So I was wondering if the page has access to the `Style.css' what exactly is preventing the browser to apply the styles to different elements.

Comment: actually <allow users="?"/> is not preventing anonymous access to your site it only allow all authenticated users. This line <deny users="?" /> is the one that prevent anonymous users. try adding it after <allow users="?"/>.

Comment: sorry didn't get you. Did I say `<allow users="?">` prevents anybody?? I am already preventing users by using <deny users="?"> the <allow users="?"> is only used for login page

Comment: hahah.. sorry my bad I haven't seen your <deny users="?"/> in your first sentence.. XD

Comment: :) I am only curious about the css. If the browser knows where it is and can read it. What is preventing it from applying the css to the page?

Comment: Which browser version are you using? Are you using IIS or some other web server like ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET and IIS? Is this behavior repeatable if you remove the rule again? If you load the page in Chrome with the developer tools enable and look at the network tab, what does it show for the CSS file?

Comment: @RichC I am using chrome and yes its ASP.NET Development Server. Using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @explunit I removed the rule again and this time the browser did not show me the styles. Instead redirected me to the login page. The status for CSS file is 302 found.

Comment: I guess I got it. Should have thoroughly tested it before posting this question :(

Comment: I did some research on your issue and running [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will light the problem. Also look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504247/asp-net-membership-css-being-blocked-by-deny-users-page-doesnt-render-correct/14941606#14941606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the additional tested rule again.

```
<location path="Style.css">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
 </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I checked the status of the CSS file in browser as specified by @explunit in comments. The status this time is 302 found and clicking the CSS link does not display the CSS file. I think the CSS was cached by the browser thats why it displayed it for the first time.