# ASP.NET Membership Provider Reset Password Failure on Remote Servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, windows-server-2008, .net-4.5

I am having trouble with the `PasswordRecovery` control on my .NET 4 Web Forms app. I am using the ASP.NET Membership Provider and Forms Authentication. I am running IIS7 on Windows 2008R2 servers.

Everything works fine when the app is running on a Win2K8 server inside my company network, but when the app is deployed to Rackspace or a client Win2K8 box, my `ResetPassword.aspx` page gets a **302 "Object Moved"** response, then redirects to my `Login.aspx` page, and does not send the Reset Password email.

Here's what Fiddler reports:

[image]

Here's the Response Headers detail from Fiddler:

[image]

I have all the Login and Password pages in the standard Account directory with it's own `web.config`:

[image]

Here's the `web.config` for the Account directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here are the `web.config` sections for the app (I shortened them where appropriate):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
                           defaultUrl="~/" 
                           protection="All" 
                           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" 
                           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add connectionStringName="MyString" 
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false"           
           enablePasswordReset="true" 
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
           applicationName="/" 
           name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" 
           type="MyCustomMembershipProviderType" />
   </providers>
</membership>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I don't believe that this is an SMTP problem, as I can successfully ping the mail server and port using telnet on the Rackspace box, but I still get the 302 when I run the ResetPassword page. **Also, everything works fine on servers inside my company network.**

Also, the Account directory has full permissions on the Rackspace server.

I checked [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504464/920506), which offers solutions of fixing the `web.config` to allow anonymous access to the page that is getting the 302, but my Accounts folder allows all access to every page in there. The other solution in that answer has to do with turning off the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in my `web.config`, which I am not sure applies here, since I am not using MVC Routing. (I'd be happy to be corrected on this, though!)

Are there some file permissions or user permissions on the Rackspace server that I need to look into, or am I missing something in my `web.config`?

I am facing a very close client deadline on this, so I could really use some help. Thanks!

**UPDATE. More code posted by request:**

PasswordRecovery Control Markup is here:

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordReset" 
                      runat="server" 
                      EnableViewState="false" 
                      ClientIDMode="Static" 
                      RenderOuterTable="false"
                      onverifyinguser="OnVerifyingUser" 
                      onsendingmail="OnSendingMail">
        <UserNameTemplate>
            <!-Here is there is just two Label and Input pairs. 
               One pair for user email, one pair for their db instance -->  
        </UserNameTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

OnSendingMail function is here:

```
protected void OnSendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{            
     e.Message.Subject = "MySubject";
     e.Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
     e.Message.Body = "ItsHtmlInRealLife";
}
```

Comment: Show your resetPassword markup and code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with some of our custom Membership Provider code, and with our error logging on remote servers. It wasn't an issue with the web.config. Thanks to all for trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I notice in your question. web.config should be like the following -

It basically restricts anonymous access to every pages inside ~/Account folder except three pages - Login.aspx, ResetPassword.aspx and Register.aspx.

### Account web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

### Root web.config

Remove authorization tag. Basically, you are saying all pages in your site are required to login.

It is not a proper way of doing it; you need at least Home Page and Login.aspx to be anonymous access.

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assume that your suggestion above is for the web.config in the Accounts folder. Is that correct? I will try it, but I am not sure why granting less access will help. My problem is that I am getting a 302 on my ResetPassword.aspx page, and I already have all the pages in the Accounts directory open to all users. Can you offer more explanation why you think this will work, please? Thanks.

Comment: This did not work. I still got the same 302 and redirect back to Login.aspx, with no email.

Comment: You cannot have `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>` in root web.config. Basically, you are saying all pages in your site are required to login.

Comment: So, your solution is for my root web.config, and not the Accounts directory web.config? Is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: The reason why I am asking these questions is that my current configuration already allows access to the ResetPassword.aspx page. You do not need to login to reach that page. The problem is what happens when you enter your email to get the passowrd , it just redirects to Login.aspx. As for the rest of the site, I do want users to go through the Login.aspx page to access the rest of the site.

Comment: Another thing that I note in the question is that I do not have any problems when I deploy the site to a Win2K8 test box inside my company network. This is with my current configuration.